# RewriteRule accept underscores and dots

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

From the following htaccess code, I want to change the URL from `site.com/user.php?id=user_id` to `site.com/u/user_id`. But, this code is valid only if the username is alphanumeric. I do not know what to do if the username contains any underscores or a dot

```
RewriteRule ^u/(\w+)/?$ user.php?id=$1
```

Is there any replacement for `\w+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use . to match any character, or define a list of allowed characters with []

The meta-character `\w` matches any letter, number or underscore.

If you want to match other characters as well, you should use something else.

The meta-character `.` matches **any** character, so this would be an option: `RewriteRule ^u/(.+)/?$ user.php?id=$1`

Alternatively, you can define a group of allowed characters between `[]`. To allow alphanumeric characters, underscores and dots, you could use `RewriteRule ^u/([a-z0-9_\.]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1`. Notice that the `.` has to be replaced in this instance, as it otherwise will be interpreted as the meta-character mentioned above and match any character.

You could also match any character **except** the `/`, which is particularly useful when matching URLs: `RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1`. The leading `^` inside the `[]` makes the character group match **anything except the listed characters**, so in this case, anything except `/`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was of a great help +1 :)